# Where is the Write Protect Screw on Notebook? NL61

Tags: laptop, write-protect

[image]

Pictured is a [CTL brand NL61](https://ctl.box.com/shared/static/66gjue7hgas931kbgzpafxpuyqsvh1io.pdf) Chromebook. I'm trying to enable developer mode but it's locked.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see it in the image but it will be a screw that looks like no other on the motherboard.

Comment: How about removing the protective fleece before looking?

Answer (score 0):

Contact CTL Support at https://support.ctl.net/hc/en-us as the user manual does not explain where it is, and their web site does not show how.